# How can I add custom filter order after spring security filter?

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, filter

My filter as follows:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class MDCFilter implements Filter {
.....
```

and application.properties

```
security.filter-order=0
```

In above settings- my filter is coming first and then security filter. But i need mdcFilter after spring security filter.

Comment: tried 
`@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChain(@Qualifier(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME) Filter securityFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(securityFilter);
    registration.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
    registration.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    return registration;
}`

Comment: and
    `@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean userInsertingMdcFilterRegistrationBean(final MDCFilter mdcFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(mdcFilter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }`

Answer (score 5):

You can put your filter next to specific spring-security filter by defining you security config like that:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MDCFilter mdcFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(mdcFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

In above example your filter will go just before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. You can also use HttpSecurity class methods `addFilterAfter(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> afterFilter)` and `addFilterAt(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> atFilter)` to specify your filter order.

Comment: Thanks, But I'm using JwtAuthenticationFilter (provided by atlassian). It didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your own Filter to go after Spring Security's you can create your own registration for Spring Security's filter and specify the order.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChain(@Qualifier(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME) Filter securityFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(securityFilter);
        registration.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
        registration.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean userInsertingMdcFilterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        UserInsertingMdcFilter userFilter = new UserInsertingMdcFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(userFilter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```